# Trying to get last business day in prior month from a date, TypeError: cannot convert datetimelike to dtype [datetime64[D]]

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the last business day in the month prior to curr_date (which is end of current month):

```
nf.loc[:,'priorBDay'] = np.busday_offset(nf.curr_date.values.astype('M8[M]') + np.timedelta64(-1, 'M'), -1, roll='forward')
```

Data type for curr_date is:

```
datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Get error:

> TypeError: cannot convert datetimelike to dtype [datetime64[D]]

curr_date is the last business day of the current month, I want to calculate the last business day of the prior month (Prior_Bday).

[image]

Comment: Please share a sample input dataframe with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: Please post in the question itself not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
nf['priorBDay'] = nf.curr_date.apply(lambda dat:
    pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1).rollback(dat) - pd.offsets.BDay())
```

The first step (*rollback*) is to move the source date to the start of
the current month, but only if the source date is not already the first
day of month.

The second step (*- BDay()*) is to shift to the previous business day.

For a couple of test dates the result is:

```
   curr_date  priorBDay
0 2019-09-10 2019-08-30
1 2020-06-10 2020-05-29
2 2020-09-10 2020-08-31
3 2020-10-30 2020-09-30
4 2020-10-31 2020-09-30
5 2020-11-01 2020-10-30
6 2020-11-02 2020-10-30
```

I assume that *curr_date* column is of *datetime* type. If not, convert it.

Note that `nf.curr_date - pd.offsets.BMonthEnd()` is a **wrong** formula.
E.g. for *2020-10-31* it yields *2020-10-30*, i.e. the last business
day in the **current** month.

Comment: Including the Oct 2020 examples is very useful - thanks!